# In Postgres: What is the most concise way to use `IS DISTINCT FROM` on multiple values?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to find all rows that have an enum column that is either NULL or otherwise distinct from a given set of enum values. I can do it with a lot of `IS DINSTINCT FROM` calls, but it's really verbose and I'd rather use `NOT IN()` syntax, but the `NULL` throws that off.

Here is an example of what I want to do in SQL, from this fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dfae4d/8

```sql
    CREATE TYPE mood AS ENUM ('sad', 'ok', 'happy');
    CREATE TABLE people (
        name text,
        current_mood mood,
        current_mood_as_text varchar
    );
    insert into people values('Mr Happy', 'happy', 'happy');
    insert into people values('Mr Sad', 'sad', 'sad');
    insert into people values('Mr Null', NULL, NULL);

    -- This doesn't return MrUnknown because of the NULL value:
    select * from people where current_mood NOT IN ('happy');

    -- This works great, and includes Mr Null:
    select * from people where current_mood IS DISTINCT FROM 'happy';

    -- But If I want to start comparing to multiple moods, it gets more verbose fast:
    SELECT * FROM people 
    WHERE current_mood IS DISTINCT FROM 'happy' AND
    current_mood IS DISTINCT FROM 'sad';

    -- You can't write this, but it's kinda what I want:
    -- SELECT * FROM people 
    -- WHERE current_mood IS DISTINCT FROM ('happy', 'sad');

    -- For the non enum column, I could do this to make my intention and code clear and concise
    SELECT * FROM people 
    WHERE coalesce(current_mood_as_text, '') NOT IN ('happy', 'sad');

    -- But if I write this, I get an error because '' is not a valid enum value
    -- SELECT * FROM people 
    -- WHERE coalesce(current_mood, '') NOT IN ('happy', 'sad');
```

Is there another way to make this sort of multiple comparison more concise?

Comment: `current_mood not in ('happy', 'sad') or current_mood is null`?

Comment: Cool - I think that will work `a_horse_with_no_name`. I'm slightly sad I can't just throw a `coalesce` or `IS DISTINCT FROM` in there, but it's not terrible. :)

Comment: `DISTINCT FROM` works with row-expressions, too.

Comment: , And there is also `NOT EXISTS(...)` [ a (primary) key would be handy, here]

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name As I remember in some version of PostgreSQL especially for arrays elements comparison `null == null` was returned `true` and `null <> null` was returned `false` unlike the classic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution with `coalesce()`:

```
select * 
from people 
where coalesce(current_mood not in ('happy', 'sad'), true)
```

[SQLFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dfae4d/13)

Comment: Woah, I didn't realize idea I could use coalesce that way, but it makes sense. The result of `NULL NOT IN ('happy', 'sad')` is NULL....I was trying to coalesce BEFORE using `not in` or `in`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
SELECT * FROM people 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT FROM (VALUES ('happy'::mood), ('sad')) v(m)
  WHERE people.current_mood = v.m
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest(IMO) way is to use `VALUES()` inside a CTE and perform `NOT EXISTS()` on that table expression:

---

```
WITH m(m) AS ( VALUES( 'happy'::mood) )
SELECT *
FROM people p
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT * FROM m
        WHERE m.m = p.current_mood
        );
```

Comment: At horse: Tnx. (I have a new keyboard;-)